# The way a program executes by line

Tags: python-3.x

```
def main():
    result1=cubeVolume(2)
    result2=cubeVolume(10)
    print("side length 2 equals",result1)
    print("side legnth 10 equals",result2)
def cubVolume(sidelength):
    volume = sideLength**3
    return volume
main()
```

Would I be correct in saying that this executes in the following sequence line?

> 9,1,2,6,7,8,3,4,5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line numbers execute as follows:

```
    1,6,9,
    1,2,
        6,7,8,
    3,
        6,7,8,
    4,5
```

`6,7,8` is your cubVolume function. This function should be cubeVolume (or more pythonicly cube_volume). Edit: I have put 1, 6, 9 in to state where the functions are being registered as suggested by poke.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification, I ended up changing my answer to that before you posted.

Comment: I would slightly modify that to be `1, 6, 9, …` at the beginning, as the file is originally interpreted from top to bottom and each function definition is executed first to register the name of the function.